# Xamarin Android: Animated Splash Screen

Tags: animation, xamarin, xamarin.android, splash-screen

I want to create an animated splash screen, but i got this error:

> Android.Content.Res.Resources+NotFoundException: File
>   res/drawable/splash_screen.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f0200bc

My code works when i change the src of the Imageview to @drawable/logo2, but then i get a static splas screen.

### SplashActivity.cs

```
[Activity(Theme = "@style/MyTheme", MainLauncher = true, NoHistory = true,     ScreenOrientation = ScreenOrientation.Portrait)]
public class SplashActivity : Activity
{
    static readonly string TAG = "X:" + typeof(SplashActivity).Name;

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Create your application here
    }

    protected override void OnResume()
    {
        base.OnResume();

        Task startupWork = new Task(() =>
            {
                Task.Delay(5000); // Simulate a bit of startup work.
            });

        startupWork.ContinueWith(t =>
            {
                StartActivity(typeof(MainActivity));
            }, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());

        startupWork.Start();
    }

    public override void OnWindowFocusChanged(bool hasFocus)
    {
        if (hasFocus)
        {
            ImageView imageView = FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.animated_android);
            AnimationDrawable animation = (AnimationDrawable)imageView.Drawable;
            animation.Start();
        }
    }
}
```

### Resources/Values/Style.xml

```
<resources>
    <style name="MyTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
     <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splash_screen</item>
     <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
   </style>
</resources>
```

### Resources/Drawable/splash_screen.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item>
    <color android:color="@color/splash_background"/>
  </item>
  <item>
     <ImageView android:id="@+id/animated_android"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:src="@anim/animate_android"
      />
  </item>
</layer-list>
```

### Resources/Anim/animate_android.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:oneshot="false">
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/logo2"
    android:duration="100" />
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/Move"
    android:duration="100" />
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/logo"
    android:duration="100" />
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/icon"
    android:duration="100" />
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/About"
    android:duration="100" />
</animation-list>
```

Comment: The error very much says the issue, it can't find your **splash_screen.xml**

Comment: yes i know, but when i change the content than can he find it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are doing a few things wrong.

You need to use a Layout and not drawable as base. In the Layout you need to find the image and set the appropriate animation to it.

This tutorial has a sample at the end to do it - [Xamarin.Forms (Android): Workaround For Splash Screen With Logo, Custom Background and Animation](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/oussamaalrifai/xamarin-forms-android-workaround-for-splash-screen-with-lo/)

The basic steps are :

1. Create the Spalsh layout
2. Create a drawabale
3. Create the animation
4. Wire them up all together in your activity (*Note that if you add animation to the "OnCreate" method, the animation will not start.*).